# Does Web Push Api support for iOS beta?

Tags: ios, push-notification, safari, beta, web-push

Apple announced support for web push notifications using standard push method as supported in other browsers on iOS safari starting in 2023. But till now there is no official updates from Apple. Does Apple started supporting web-push api standard on beta version of iOS on safari for early testing?

If latest iOS beta version enabled web-push notification feature then how can I test web-push on iOS beta for early testing?